# Quarkus AwsProxyRequest context authorizer not correctly set

Tags: quarkus

I've set up the following test and send AwsProxyRequest to mock listening on "/_ lambda_"(similar example [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http)).
The call is successful.

```
@QuarkusTest
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, JMSException {
        AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest = new AwsProxyRequest();
        AwsProxyRequestContext requestContext = new AwsProxyRequestContext();
        ApiGatewayAuthorizerContext authorizer = new ApiGatewayAuthorizerContext();
        authorizer.setContextValue("item", "[\"TestEditor\"]");
        requestContext.setAuthorizer(authorizer);
        awsProxyRequest.setRequestContext(requestContext);
        given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .body(awsProxyRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/_lambda_")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);

        File document = new File("src/test/resources/document.xml");
        final io.restassured.response.Response response = given()
                .body(new String(new FileInputStream(document).readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .contentType(ContentType.XML)
                .accept(ContentType.XML)
                .when()
                .post("/documents");
        final String xml = response.body().asString();
        response
                .then()
                .statusCode(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode());
   }
}
```

AwsProxyRequest is injected with @Context in the POST method handler and also there seems to be some context but the authorizer is null even if I've set it in the test as shown above.

```
@Path("/documents")
public class API {

    @POST
    public Response sendDocument(@Context AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest, String workflowDocument)    {
         //Authorizer is null here 
         awsProxyRequestContext.getRequestContext().getAuthorizer().getContextValue("applicationTypeNames");

    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you can use @InjectMock from the Context and assign the value of the requestContext to it using Mockito.

```
@QuarkusTest
public class Test {

    @Context
    @InjectMock
    AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest;

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, JMSException {
        AwsProxyRequestContext requestContext = new AwsProxyRequestContext();
        ApiGatewayAuthorizerContext authorizer = new ApiGatewayAuthorizerContext();
        authorizer.setContextValue("item", "[\"TestEditor\"]");
        requestContext.setAuthorizer(authorizer);
        
        when(awsProxyRequest.getRequestContext()).thenReturn(requestContext);

        given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .when()
                .post("/_lambda_")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200);

        ...
   }
}
```